# How to target specific value inside of the deployment.yaml file?

Tags: azure, function, kubernetes, azure-devops, kubernetes-helm

I have my values.yaml as below

```
account:
  - name: firstName
    value: roberto
  - name: lastName
    value: fabric
  - name: PORT
    value: 5000
```

It seems that by doing this, I'm not able to pull the information that I need. Example:

```
accounts:
  - name: acountTest01
    value: "{{ .Values.account.firstName}}"
  - name: account2
    value: "{{ .Values.account.lastName }}"

accounts:
      {{ .Values.account }}
```

The main problem in here is that I would like to refer to the  'PORT' only instead of getting all the values. Does anyone knows what can be done from my side to correct this situation?

Comment: Where are you trying to use PORT?

Comment: You can try this- {{  .Values.account.PORT }} without ` "" `(double quotes) after changing the yaml file from name and value format to name: value format.

Comment: My application is using a variable to pass this port at a building time and for this reason, I would like to know how to pass this variable into the deployment file from the helm chart.

Answer (score 0):

Change your *values.yaml* to

```yaml
account:
  firstName: roberto
  lastName: fabric
  port: 5000
```

There is no point in using lists for this type of data.

Then you can get `port` value with `{{ .Values.account.port }}`

Comment: This is just imaginary values that I created since I will not be posting the real values, this is just to give an example of what I'm looking for